# Elements with position "fixed" inside an iframe are not rendering in Safari

Tags: css, macos, browser, safari, webkit

We are experiencing a problem where elements with `position: fixed;` **within an iframe** are not being rendered correctly. We only noticed this on macOS in Safari.

Here is how it should look:

[image]

Here is what Safari on macOS looks like (on page load):

[image]

On page load the top and bottom bars are not visible. They are in the DOM taking up space and can be clicked but they have not been "rendered" by the browser. As you can see in the image above the bars appear as white space.

If we force a redraw via JS, CSS or by resizing the browser the bars will appear. We are however not looking for a solution for how to force redraw. Our question is why is this happening in the first place?

You can find a live example here:

https://testing.enuvo.ch/user/collect/#collector#/user/overlay

PS: It does not always happen. Sometimes, when resizing the browser and trying again, it will display correctly. We hope you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure on the redraw but an issue I wanna point out, your noscript block renders the tags of the text you fed it.

Comment: @abluejelly Thanks for the notice. This must have happened when we copied the source code to put it on this testing server (to make it accessible to you guys).

Answer (score 7):

So there are some glitches with `position: fixed` and `z-index`. Some of the older browsers treat it a bit differently and deal with stacking contexts in a different way.

After a bit of trial and error I've managed to get it working with injected stylesheet by adding:

```
#ol-main-header,
#cl-footer {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Also you should be able to remove the unnecesarry `z-index: 99999`. Hope that helps.

Comment: While it seems to work fine in Safari, it adds noticeable "jank" when the overlay opens in Chrome on Windows :-/ Any way around this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what's wrong without seeing it. If you could do the change in the test env I could check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and yep, it's really weird. 
Have you thought about a cache problem ? 
Safari has a unique behavior for caching iframes, and maybe your problem come from these.

Could you try to change HTTP headers for this iframe to disable cache like this ?

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: 0
```

Here is an example in PHP :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, it is still happening. You can see it here: https://testing.enuvo.ch/user2/collect/#collector#/user2/overlay/

Comment: Just to be sure, could you just make a quick change on the link of iframe ? 
Could you change the current link by : 
     /user2/overlay/?t=timestamp

Or in php : 
/user2/overlay/?t=<?= time(); ?>

Comment: Done! Still happening though :-/

Comment: I had similar problem on my iPhone without iframe.

Answer (score -3):

you have to write css in iframe file not your view file.

Comment: Pla do not add irreleveant links to your answers because these may be reported as spam.